# Crackling sound with usb interface

Tags: pulseaudio

When I want to use a zoom h2n device to play audio, which can be used as usb interface, the sound is distorted.

Depending on whether its set to 44100hz or 48000hz, one of youtube or bandcamp won't work. When playing sound through bandcamp and then at the same time through youtube, both work fine. But when only one source is playing at a time, one will always be distorted. Hence I guess this has to do with the sample rate somehow. For 44100hz, youtube is distorted, for 48000hz bandcamp is.

You can even hear how the pitch is somehow changed. So this is a super wild guess, but it sounds like as if it tries to output those samples that are in the buffer, which happens faster than it should be due to mismatching sample rates, but then the buffer is empty and it has to wait for more samples to accumulate, which produces the distortion.

EDIT: see [Pulseaudio detects wrong sample rate. Forcing pulseaudio a sample rate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585789/pulseaudio-detects-wrong-sample-rate-forcing-pulseaudio-a-sample-rate)

Answer (score 0):

<s>Disabling all other soundcards (the internal "Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller" and "Ellesmere HDMI Audio") in `pavucontrol` -> "Configuration" by setting the "Profile" to "Off" and only leaving the "H4 Digital Recorder" at "Analog Stereo Duplex", it works.</s>

Looks like my system somehow cannot handle multiple active soundcards.

**EDIT**

no, didn't help

Comment: Disabling unused soundcards (the HDMI output) also helped to make jack work. Since I have all sorts of ridiculous problems with jack all the time I unfortunately cannot recall which specific problem was solved by this. Furthermore, I heard that having multiple soundcards can apparently lead to problems with them getting out of sync or something, whatever that is supposed to mean.